# Exclude future signals

Tags: python, pandas

I dont know if I'm solving this the right way - a 1 Signal should return 1 Buy and then no 1 Buy until -1 Signal and then -1 Sell is returned. Same thing for -1 Sell. Anyone got any smart input?

```py
    df.loc[0, "Buy"] = 0
    x = 0
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if df.loc[i, "Signal"] == 1 and x == 0:
            df.loc[i, "Buy"] = 1
            x = 1
            y=0
        elif df.loc[i, "Signal"] == -1 and y == 0:
            df.loc[i, "Buy"] = -1
            x = 0
            y=1
        else:
            df.loc[i+1, "Buy"] = ""



Dataframe
Signal  Buy
0   
1       1
1   
1   
0   
0   
-1      -1
0   
0   
1       1
1   
0   
0   
-1      -1
0   
-1  
0   
-1  
0   
0
```

Comment: You really need to post a sample of your dataframe that we can run your code on.

Comment: Break out of the loop after finding the first buy?

Comment: @Chris should been provided now ***nicomp*** - first 1 signal should give Buy, then no Buys for the following 1 signals UNTIL a Sell -1 is returned, then it should return the next 1 Buy. So multiples Buys over the dataframe